# Optimize mergesort algorithm

Tags: python, performance, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel, mergesort

I just started Stanford Coursera algorithms course and I wrote this mergesort based on what was shown:

```
def mergesort(n):

    if len(n) <= 1:
        return n

    length = len(n) // 2
    A = mergesort(n[:length])
    B = mergesort(n[length:])
    iterA = 0
    iterB = 0
    C = []
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if A[iterA] <= B[iterB]:
            C.append(A[iterA])
            iterA += 1
        elif B[iterB] <= A[iterA]:
            C.append(B[iterB])
            iterB += 1
        if iterA == len(A):
            C += B[iterB:]
            break
        if iterB == len(B):
            C += A[iterA:]
            break
    return C
```

It runs decently well but I was wondering what optimizations I could make to it to improve performance? Currently does 1 million numbers in ~8.5 seconds.

Comment: Should of fixed it I forgot the equal sign when comparing 2 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is a good idea to follow conventions.
For Python, foremost the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).

> Write docstrings for all public modules, functions, classes, and methods.

The conventional name for values obtained, but not used is `_`:
`for _ in range(len(items)):`
Where there are two alternatives that together cover all possibilities,
check for one to handle in the "then-branch", and leave the complement to an `else`.
You check both lists to have reached their end in each iteration, but only one item has been consumed.

```
def mergesort(items):
    """ Return a list containing the items in ascending order.
        The result may be items itself.
    """
    n = len(items)
    if n <= 1:  # 2:  # low hanging fruit, then again: this way lies madness
        return items  # if n <=1 or items[0] <= items[1] else [items[1], items[0]]
    # what would be notable performance improvements?
    half = n // 2
    a = mergesort(items[:half])
    last_a = half - 1
    b = mergesort(items[half:])
    last_b = n - half - 1
    i_a = i_b = 0
    c = []
    while True:
        if a[i_a] <= b[i_b]:
            c.append(a[i_a])
            if last_a <= i_a:
                return c + b[i_b:]
            i_a += 1
        else:  # b[i_b] < a[i_a]
            c.append(b[i_b])
            if last_b <= i_b:
                return c + a[i_a:]
            i_b += 1
```

(While `i` is perfect for *the* short-lived index/iteration variable, `i_a`&`i_b` look off.)
(note the duplication between *a* and *b* not eased by introducing `last_a`/`b`.)

---

> I was wondering what optimizations I could make to [my `mergesort()`] to improve performance?

Glad you took a break there and did not present code difficult to read for all the improvements tried.
Things to do regarding performance:
• Model performance:
 · Input: size, range, distribution, proportion of duplicates
 · Resources: cores, threads, main memory, whatever
• for "microbenchmarks", find a framework rather than trying to roll your own
• before starting to modify the code, have some functional test in place
  (starting with comparing results with "the original")
• measure on different "platforms", if at all possible
• for Python try [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org) or similar

---

[Common starting points for improving mergesort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Optimizing_merge_sort):
• allocate a single "temporary buffer", *once*
  (advantage to slicing the original/outer input: works for any iterable, not just lists.)
• try to handle *run*s, starting with [exploiting runs in the input](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort)
• for "small sets", avoid the setup of mergesort by using a simpler sort
  (Shell sort may be interesting to compare to insertion sort, here.)

Comment: One implementation to scrutinise: [Kelly Bundy's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/253364)